# Combining Latex files with different preambles

Tags: input, include, import, combine

I am in the process of writing a Python program that scrapes exam questions in tex files from a website and combines them to create a new paper. The questions are picked by random from a spreadsheet, so that questions from various years (and therefore from different latex files) may be combined. [Here](https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/87/87-S2.tex) is an example of such a paper (1987), and [here](https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/18/18-S3.tex) is an example from a much newer paper (2018).

The preambles are considerably distinct and this makes it difficult to simply include them into the same latex file. How could I, for example, take a particular question from the older paper and another question from the newer paper and produce a single pdf file? I have attempted to use the `subfiles` and `standalone` packages but I get bombarded with errors. I have also considered compiling each latex file separately and concatenating them using `pdfpages` or a similar command line utility but I would like to avoid having only a single question per page. I have thought about programmatically retrieving the "union" of the preambles from the two (or more) files and simply substituting in each `\question` in a single latex file, but this is a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I have opted to use the combine document class and structure the main document similar to below:

```latex
\documentclass{combine}

\begin{document}

\begin{papers}

\let\clearpage\relax

\import{question-file-1}

\import{question-file-2}

\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

The use of the `papers` environment proved necessary, as did the line `\let\clearpage\relax` to ensure that the documents do not simply start at the next page. Compiling the main document produces a consistent pdf file, but there are many "X already defined!" errors which thankfully do not disrupt the compilation of the pdf (and especially so after passing the `interaction=nonstopmode` argument to `latexmk`).

Comment: I would address all errors in compilation, even if it does produce a PDF in the end. Without seeing what these included files look like, I can't tell you how, but I doubt it would be that hard to make your python script strip out the redundant definitions.